# Using Reflection on Type T to create Expression<Func<T, TValue>> for Properties that have attributes

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm currently exploring the viability to encapsulate some logic that would typically be iterative. Using a 3rd party library it has a generic Html Helper method that allows you to map properties from a Generic T class to a table component. Typically you'd have to write something to the effect of:

```
HtmlHelper.GenerateTable<ClassName>
.configure(tableDefinition =>{
  // Adding each property you want to render here
  tableDefinition.add(myClassRef => myClassRef.propertyA);
  tableDefinition.add(myClassRef => myClassRef.propertyB);
})
```

I'm exploring the idea of adding attributes to properties such as a standard Display attribute and then using reflection, adding that property to the container. The `add` method only accepts an argument of type `Expression<Func<T, TValue>>`. With my current understanding of reflection I know I can property identify properties that would be applicable by looping through `PropertyInfo` and checking for the attribute I want using `GetCustomAttribute`.

What I'm stumped on is if it's possible using reflection to supply the argument type that the add method expects?

I'll throw the helper method logic I've started using so far. My assumption is that this is leading me towards Expression and Lambda classes, but I haven't been able to flesh out anything that works since I don't technically have a `TValue`.

```
var t = typeof(T);
List<PropertyInfo> properties = t.GetProperties().ToList();
foreach(var prop in properties)
{
    var attr = (DisplayAttribute[])prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false);
    if (attr.Length > 0)
    {
        // TODO: Call add with expression?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this fairly easily with the methods on the [`Expression` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=net-5.0). To start with, it's easiest to write expressions using lambdas (e.g. `Expression<Func<A, B>> expr = x => x.PropertyA`), then inspect it in a debugger to see what the compiler constructs.

In your case, something like this should work:

```
// The parameter passed into the expression (myClassRef) in your code
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "myClassRef");

// Access the property described by the PropertyInfo 'prop' on the
// myClassRef parameter
var propertyAccess = Expression.Property(parameter, prop);
// Since we're returning an 'object', we'll need to make sure we box value types.
var box = Expression.Convert(propertyAccess, typeof(object));

// Construct the whole lambda
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(box, parameter);
tableDefinition.add(lambda);
```

Note that I'm passing an `Expression<Func<T, object>>` into `add`, rather than an `Expression<Func<T, TValue>>`. I'm *guessing* that this doesn't matter, and it avoids having to call `add` using reflection. When I've written methods similar to `add` in the past, I don't care about `TValue` at all: I just inspect the `Expression` and fetch the `PropertyInfo` from the property access.

If you do need to pass an `Expression<Func<T, TValue>>` you'll have to do something like:

```
var delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T), prop.PropertyType);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, propertyAccess, parameter);

// I'm assuming that your `add` method looks like:
// void add<T, TValue>(Expression<Func<T, TValue>> expr)
// I'm also assuming there's only one method called 'add' -- be smarter in that
// 'GetMethod' call if not.
var addMethod = typeof(TableDefinition)
    .GetMethod("add")
    .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), prop.PropertyType);

addMethod.Invoke(tableDefinition, new object[] { lambda });
```

Note that you don't need the `Expression.Convert(..., typeof(object))` in this case.

Comment: I confirmed this does work with the library when I'm only dealing with strings. But one of the properties I was testing is a Nullable<double>, which it throws an exception at runtime converting something Nullable to object. Would Nullable types point towards the Generic Method approach or could it still be resolved using that initial proposed solution?

Comment: To provide slightly more context to my previous statement, the exception thrown is Expression of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Double]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'. Which makes sense, but how to alter the statement isn't very clear for Nullables.

Comment: Ah, you'll need to add `Expression.Convert(..., typeof(object))`. See my edit. It's entirely possible that your third-party method doesn't know how to parse this, so you might need to fall back to the second approach, but give it a shot

Comment: I happened to stumble upon that a little bit ago while playing around and it worked to address nullable types. DateTime doesn't behave like other nullable value types even after the conversion so I ended up detecting DateTime explicitly and creating a special rule converting DateTime so thats probably the sole remaining area of improvement I can come up with.

Comment: That's weird -- have you got more information on that? It seems to work fine here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4r3vaI

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't throw an error, its the client-side output that tells me its off after fiddling with output and types. For a nullable type the 3rd party library fails to properly associate the property with it's name if I perform Convert on it. This is true for nullable Datetime and Double. If build an explicit cast expression for that nullable property everything works correctly. As soon as I Inject the Convert it can't properly identify field names.e.g. `Expression.Lambda<Func<T, Nullable<DateTime>>>(propertyAccess, parameter);` without Convert. Clunky but functioning.

Comment: Aha, it must just be failing to parse the `Expression.Convert` properly I guess. Oh well.